# How to Test Gol App Engine apps locally on Win 10 and use app.yaml

Tags: go, google-app-engine, gcloud

In Google's latest docs, they say to test Go 1.12+ apps locally, one should just go build.

However, this doesn't take into account all the routing etc that would happen in the app engine utilizing the app.yaml config file.

I see that the dev_appserver.py is still included in the sdk. But it doesn't seem to work in Windows 10.

How does one test their Go App Engine App locally with the app.yaml. ie: as an actual emulated app engine app.

Thank you!

Comment: Limit app.yaml routing to static_files, static_dir and a single `/.*` script.  Write the application to handle the static assets.  Run application directly as recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, if your application consists of just the default service I would recommend to follow @cerise-limón comment suggestion. In general, it is recommended for the routing logic of the application to be handled within the code. Although I'm not a Go programmer, for single service applications that use static_files and static_dir there shouldn't be any problems when testing the application locally. You might also deploy the new version without promoting traffic to it in order to test it as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/testing-and-deploying-your-app#testing-on-app-engine).

On the other hand, if your application is distributed across multiple services and the routing is managed through the [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-requests-are-routed#routing_with_a_dispatch_file) configuration file you might follow two approaches:

- Test each service locally one by one. This could be the way to go if each service has a single responsibility/functionality that could be tested in isolation from the other services. In fact, with this kind of architecture the testing procedure would be more or less the same as for single service applications.
- Run all services locally at once and build your own routing layer. This option would allow to test applications where services needs to reach one another in order to fulfill the requests made to them.

Another approach that is widely used is to have a separate project for development purposes where you could just deploy the application and observe it's behavior in the App Engine environment. As for applications with highly coupled services it would be the easiest option. But it largely depends on your budget.